# Broken apt dependency tree

Tags: ubuntu, installation, dependencies, apt

I was upgrading Ubuntu 16.04 to 17.04, when some packaged failed to upgrade. This left the apt dependency in a broken state. I tried some other answers online, but I am afraid this only complicated the situation. Following a particular answer, I realised that the easiest way to fix these is manual installation of packages from ubuntu archive. I just want to know the upgrades/installs that I should perform, to fix the situation.

Output of various commands:-

install:-

```
$sudo apt install yum-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... 50%
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python : PreDepends: python-minimal (= 2.7.11-2) but 2.7.14-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
          Depends: libpython-stdlib (= 2.7.11-2) but 2.7.14-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
 python-all : Depends: python (= 2.7.14-2ubuntu1) but 2.7.11-2 is to be installed
 python-all-dev : Depends: python (= 2.7.14-2ubuntu1) but 2.7.11-2 is to be installed
 python-dev : Depends: python (= 2.7.14-2ubuntu1) but 2.7.11-2 is to be installed
 resetter : Depends: python-qt4 (>= 4.10) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: python-mechanize (>= 1:0.2.5) but it is not going to be installed
 yum-utils : Depends: python-iniparse but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

upgrade:-

```
$sudo apt upgrade gnome-control-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python : PreDepends: python-minimal (= 2.7.11-2) but 2.7.14-2ubuntu1 is installed
          Depends: libpython-stdlib (= 2.7.11-2) but 2.7.14-2ubuntu1 is installed
 python-all : Depends: python (= 2.7.14-2ubuntu1) but 2.7.11-2 is installed
 python-all-dev : Depends: python (= 2.7.14-2ubuntu1) but 2.7.11-2 is installed
 python-dev : Depends: python (= 2.7.14-2ubuntu1) but 2.7.11-2 is installed
 resetter : Depends: python-qt4 (>= 4.10) but it is not installed
            Depends: python-mechanize (>= 1:0.2.5) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Fix broken install:-

```
$sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  account-plugin-facebook account-plugin-flickr account-plugin-google account-plugin-tools
  accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas accountsservice-ubuntu-touch-schemas address-book-service
  app-install-data apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu biometryd-bin cgmanager click click-apparmor
  content-hub espeak-data evolution-data-server-online-accounts evolution-data-server-utouch
  folks-common fonts-font-awesome gcc-6-base:i386 gir1.2-appstreamglib-1.0 gir1.2-click-0.4
  gir1.2-gee-0.8 gir1.2-gusb-1.0 gir1.2-mutter-0 gksu glassfish-javaee gnome-backgrounds
  gnome-contacts googletest history-service hwdata i965-va-driver:i386 icoutils indicator-network
  indicator-transfer indicator-transfer-download-manager ipython-notebook-common kate-data
  kde-baseapps-data kde-runtime-data kde-style-breeze kdelibs5-data libaacs0:i386
  libaccount-plugin-1.0-0 libaccount-plugin-facebook libaccount-plugin-flickr
  libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth libaccount-plugin-google libaccounts-qt5-1
  libandroid-properties1 libass5 libattica0.4 libattica0.4:i386 libaudio2:i386
  libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libavcodec57:i386
  libavformat57:i386 libavutil55:i386 libbdplus0:i386 libbiometryd1 libblas-common libbluray1
  libbluray1:i386 libbluray2:i386 libboost-atomic-dev libboost-atomic1.61.0
  libboost-atomic1.62-dev libboost-atomic1.62.0 libboost-chrono-dev libboost-chrono1.61.0
  libboost-chrono1.62-dev libboost-chrono1.62.0 libboost-context-dev libboost-context1.61.0
  libboost-context1.62-dev libboost-context1.62.0 libboost-coroutine-dev libboost-coroutine1.61.0
  libboost-coroutine1.62-dev libboost-coroutine1.62.0 libboost-date-time-dev
  libboost-date-time1.61.0 libboost-date-time1.62-dev libboost-dev libboost-exception-dev
  libboost-exception1.62-dev libboost-fiber-dev libboost-fiber1.62-dev libboost-fiber1.62.0
  libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-filesystem1.61.0 libboost-filesystem1.62-dev libboost-graph-dev
  libboost-graph-parallel-dev libboost-graph-parallel1.61.0 libboost-graph-parallel1.62-dev
  libboost-graph-parallel1.62.0 libboost-graph1.61.0 libboost-graph1.62-dev libboost-graph1.62.0
  libboost-iostreams-dev libboost-iostreams1.61.0 libboost-iostreams1.62-dev libboost-locale-dev
  libboost-locale1.61.0 libboost-locale1.62-dev libboost-locale1.62.0 libboost-log-dev
  libboost-log1.61.0 libboost-log1.62-dev libboost-log1.62.0 libboost-math-dev libboost-math1.61.0
  libboost-math1.62-dev libboost-math1.62.0 libboost-mpi-dev libboost-mpi1.61.0
  libboost-mpi1.62-dev libboost-mpi1.62.0 libboost-program-options-dev
  libboost-program-options1.61.0 libboost-program-options1.62-dev libboost-program-options1.62.0
  libboost-python-dev libboost-python1.61.0 libboost-python1.62-dev libboost-python1.62.0
  libboost-random-dev libboost-random1.61.0 libboost-random1.62-dev libboost-regex-dev
  libboost-regex1.61.0 libboost-regex1.62-dev libboost-serialization-dev
  libboost-serialization1.61.0 libboost-serialization1.62-dev libboost-signals-dev
  libboost-signals1.61.0 libboost-signals1.62-dev libboost-signals1.62.0 libboost-system-dev
  libboost-system1.61.0 libboost-system1.62-dev libboost-test-dev libboost-test1.61.0
  libboost-test1.62-dev libboost-test1.62.0 libboost-thread-dev libboost-thread1.61.0
  libboost-thread1.62-dev libboost-timer-dev libboost-timer1.61.0 libboost-timer1.62-dev
  libboost-timer1.62.0 libboost-tools-dev libboost-type-erasure-dev libboost-type-erasure1.62-dev
  libboost-type-erasure1.62.0 libboost-wave-dev libboost-wave1.61.0 libboost-wave1.62-dev
  libboost-wave1.62.0 libboost1.62-dev libboost1.62-tools-dev libbsh-java libcairo2:i386
  libcamel-1.2-59 libchamplain-0.12-0 libchromaprint0 libchromaprint0:i386 libchromaprint1:i386
  libclassworlds-java libclick-0.4-0 libclucene-core1v5:i386 libcommons-compress-java
  libcommons-httpclient-java libcommons-lang-java libconnectivity-qt1 libcontent-hub-glib0
  libcontent-hub0 libcrystalhd3:i386 libcups2:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libdbus-cpp5
  libdbusmenu-qt2:i386 libdirectfb-1.2-9 libdlrestrictions1:i386 libdom4j-java libdoxia-core-java
  libeasymock-java libebook-1.2-16 libebur128-1 libeclipse-aether-java libertine-xmir-tools
  libertined libespeak1 libevent-core-2.0-5 libexiv2-14:i386 libfabric1 libfolks-eds25
  libfolks-telepathy25 libfolks25 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386
  libgeronimo-ejb-3.0-spec-java libgeronimo-jms-1.1-spec-java libgeronimo-osgi-support-java
  libgeronimo-validation-1.0-spec-java libgflags2.2 libgflags2v5 libgksu2-0 libglib2.0-0:i386
  libgme0:i386 libgmime-2.6-0 libgmp10:i386 libgnutls30:i386 libgomp1:i386 libgoogle-glog0v5
  libgsm1:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgtkspell3-3-0 libgtop-2.0-10 libhardware2 libhdf5-10
  libhdf5-cpp-11 libhistoryservice0 libhogweed4:i386 libhud2 libhunspell-1.4-0 libhwloc-dev
  libhwloc-plugins libhwloc5 libhybris libhybris-common1 libibverbs-dev libice6:i386 libicu57:i386
  libidn11:i386 libindicator-transfer0 libjasper1 libjaxen-java libjbig0:i386 libjdom1-java
  libjdom2-java libjetty8-java libjetty9-java libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386 libjs-highlight
  libjs-highlight.js libjs-jquery-ui libjs-marked libjs-sphinxdoc libk5crypto3:i386
  libkdecore5:i386 libkdeui5:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkf5gpgmepp5 libkf5style5 libkio5:i386
  libkonq5-templates libkparts4:i386 libkprintutils4:i386 libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386
  liblcms2-2:i386 libleveldb1v5 liblibertine1 liblightdm-qt5-3-0 liblircclient0 liblivemedia52
  liblivemedia57 libllvm3.8 libllvm3.8:i386 libllvm4.0 libllvm4.0:i386 liblouis10
  libmaven-archiver-java libmaven2-core-java libmecab2 libmedia1 libmediascanner-2.0-4 libmiral2
  libmircommon6 libmirplatform13 libmirplatform15 libmirplatform16 libmirserver41 libmirserver43
  libmirserver45 libmission-control-plugins0 libmng2:i386 libmodplug1 libmodplug1:i386
  libmozjs-24-0v5 libmozjs-38-0 libmp3lame0:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libmutter-0-0
  libmysqlclient20:i386 libnettle6:i386 libnm-glib-vpn1 libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0 libnuma-dev
  libnuma1:i386 libobjenesis-java libogg0:i386 libonline-accounts-client1
  libonline-accounts-daemon1 libonline-accounts-qt1 libopencv-core2.4v5 libopencv-imgproc2.4v5
  libopenjp2-7:i386 libopenjpeg5 libopenjpeg5:i386 libopenmpi-dev libopenmpi2 libopenmpt0:i386
  libopus0:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 liborcus-0.11-0 libosgi-annotation-java libosgi-compendium-java
  libosgi-core-java liboxideqt-qmlplugin liboxideqtcore0 liboxideqtquick0 libp11-kit0:i386
  libpam-cgfs libpanel-applet0 libpanel-applet2 libpay2 libperl5.22 libperl5.24 libphonon4
  libpixman-1-0:i386 libplexus-ant-factory-java libplexus-archiver-java libplexus-bsh-factory-java
  libplexus-cli-java libplexus-component-metadata-java libplexus-container-default-java
  libplexus-container-default1.5-java libplexus-containers-java libplexus-containers1.5-java
  libplexus-interactivity-api-java libplexus-io-java libpng16-16:i386 libpolkit-qt-1-1
  libpoppler61 libpoppler64 libpsm-infinipath1 libpython3.5 libpython3.5-dev libqca2
  libqca2-plugins libqdjango-db0 libqdox-java libqdox2-java libqgsttools-p1 libqimageblitz4:i386
  libqmenumodel0 libqofono-qt5-0 libqpdf17 libqt4-dbus:i386 libqt4-declarative:i386
  libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-qt3support libqt4-script:i386 libqt4-sql:i386 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386
  libqt4-svg:i386 libqt4-xml:i386 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 libqt5clucene5 libqt5concurrent5
  libqt5contacts5 libqt5feedback5 libqt5multimedia5-plugins libqt5multimediaquick-p5
  libqt5multimediawidgets5 libqt5organizer5 libqt5positioning5 libqt5quicktest5 libqt5sensors5
  libqt5systeminfo5 libqt5versit5 libqt5xmlpatterns5 libqtcore4:i386 libqtdbus4:i386
  libqtgui4:i386 libraw15 librdmacm1 librtmp1:i386 libschroedinger-1.0-0
  libschroedinger-1.0-0:i386 libservlet3.0-java libshine3:i386 libsignon-extension1
  libsignon-plugins-common1 libsignon-qt5-1 libsm6:i386 libsnappy-java libsnappy-jni
  libsnappy1v5:i386 libsolid4:i386 libsoxr0:i386 libspeex1:i386 libspring-aop-java
  libspring-beans-java libspring-context-java libspring-core-java libspring-expression-java
  libspring-instrument-java libssh-gcrypt-4:i386 libstreamanalyzer0v5:i386 libstreams0v5:i386
  libswresample2:i386 libsystemsettings1 libtasn1-6:i386 libtelepathy-qt4-2 libtelepathy-qt5-0
  libtheora0:i386 libthreadweaver4 libthumbnailer-qt1.0 libtiff5:i386 libtracker-sparql-1.0-0
  libtrust-store2 libtwolame0:i386 libubuntu-app-launch3 libubuntu-application-api3
  libubuntu-download-manager-client1 libubuntu-download-manager-common1
  libubuntu-location-service3 libubuntu-platform-hardware-api3 libubuntumetrics5
  libubuntuoneauth-2.0-0 libudm-common1 libudm-priv-common1 libunity-action-qt1 liburcu4
  libusermetricsinput1 libusermetricsoutput1 libva-drm1:i386 libva-x11-1:i386 libva1:i386
  libvdpau1:i386 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386 libvorbisfile3:i386 libvpx3 libvpx3:i386
  libvpx4:i386 libwagon-java libwavpack1:i386 libwebp6:i386 libwebpmux2 libwebpmux2:i386
  libwebpmux3:i386 libx264-148:i386 libx265-110 libx265-110:i386 libx265-130:i386 libx265-79
  libx265-79:i386 libx86-1 libxapian22v5 libxbean-java libxbean-reflect-java libxcb-render0:i386
  libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxen-4.7 libxen-4.8 libxi6:i386 libxml2:i386 libxom-java
  libxpp2-java libxpp3-java libxrender1:i386 libxt6:i386 libxvidcore4:i386 libxz-java
  libzvbi0:i386 linux-headers-4.8.0-58 linux-headers-4.8.0-58-generic linux-image-4.8.0-58-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.8.0-58-generic linux-signed-image-4.8.0-58-generic mediascanner2.0
  mesa-va-drivers:i386 mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386 mir-client-platform-mesa5
  mir-graphics-drivers-desktop mir-platform-graphics-mesa-kms12 mir-platform-graphics-mesa-kms13
  mir-platform-graphics-mesa-x12 mir-platform-graphics-mesa-x13 mir-platform-input-evdev6
  mir-platform-input-evdev7 mpi-default-bin mpi-default-dev musescore-soundfont-gm
  network-manager-openvpn node-sigmund ntrack-module-libnl-0 openmpi-bin openmpi-common
  oxideqt-codecs oxygen-icon-theme oxygen5-icon-theme perl-modules-5.22 perl-modules-5.24 phonon
  phonon-backend-gstreamer phonon-backend-gstreamer-common php7.0-xml plainbox-provider-checkbox
  plainbox-provider-resource-generic plainbox-secure-policy pm-utils policykit-unity8 pyotherside
  python-backports-abc python-concurrent.futures python-jinja2 python-markupsafe
  python-singledispatch python-tornado python-zmq python3-apparmor-click python3-checkbox-support
  python3-click-package python3-guacamole python3-jinja2 python3-libertine python3-padme
  python3-plainbox python3-psutil python3-pyasn1 python3-pyparsing python3-xlsxwriter
  python3.5-dev qmenumodel-qml qml-module-biometryd qml-module-io-thp-pyotherside qml-module-ofono
  qml-module-pamauthentication0.1 qml-module-qmltermwidget1.0 qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel
  qml-module-qt-labs-settings qml-module-qtfeedback qml-module-qtmultimedia
  qml-module-qtqml-statemachine qml-module-qtquick-xmllistmodel qml-module-qtsysteminfo
  qml-module-qttest qml-module-ubuntu-connectivity qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts
  qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts-client qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts2
  qml-module-ubuntu-performancemetrics qml-module-ubuntu-thumbnailer0.1 qmlscene qt-at-spi:i386
  qtcontact5-galera qtdeclarative5-accounts-plugin qtdeclarative5-dev-tools
  qtdeclarative5-gsettings1.0 qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin qtdeclarative5-test-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-content1 qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-download-manager0.1
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-telephony0.1 qtdeclarative5-unity-action-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-unity-notifications-plugin qtubuntu-desktop rename repowerd repowerd-data
  signon-keyring-extension signon-plugin-oauth2 signon-plugin-password signon-ui signon-ui-service
  signon-ui-x11 signond sqlite3 suru-icon-theme telepathy-mission-control-5 telephony-service
  thumbnailer-service tone-generator ubuntu-app-launch-tools ubuntu-application-api3-desktop
  ubuntu-application-api3-test ubuntu-download-manager ubuntu-mobile-icons ubuntu-push-client
  ubuntu-ui-toolkit-theme ubuntuone-client-data ubuntuone-credentials-common
  unity-control-center-signon unity-plugin-scopes unity-scope-gdrive unity-scope-mediascanner2
  unity-system-compositor usermetricsservice va-driver-all:i386 vbetool vdpau-driver-all:i386 xmir
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libqt4-help libqt4-scripttools libqt4-test libqtassistantclient4 python python-mechanize
  python-qt4
Suggested packages:
  python-doc python-qt4-dbg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libqt4-help libqt4-scripttools libqt4-test libqtassistantclient4 python-mechanize python-qt4
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python
1 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
10 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/3,139 kB of archives.
After this operation, 16.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up python-minimal (2.7.14-2ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/compileall.py", line 16, in <module>
    import struct
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/struct.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _struct import *
ImportError: No module named _struct
dpkg: error processing package python-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried several other answers, but if you want, I can add output of other commands

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt install aptitude
sudo aptitude install yum-utils
sudo apt autoremove
```